# What is the difference between the different implementations of clone() in ConstraintSet?

Tags: android, methods, android-constraintlayout

According to the [docs for `ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#clone(android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout)), there are three implementations of the `clone()` method:

- `void clone(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout)`
- `void clone(ConstraintSet set)`
- `void clone(Context context, int constraintLayoutId)`

The explanation for each version in the docs is a little vague, so I'm not entirely clear on what the differences between the three are and when I should use each one. I've been able to use the first one with no problems or anything whenever I needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintSet` includes this private field:

```
private HashMap<Integer, ConstraintSet.Constraint> mConstraints;
```

Each of the three `clone()` methods will remove all existing entries from this `Map` and then fill it back up based on what you've passed in. In essence, each of these methods will turn whichever `ConstraintSet` instance you're invoking them on into a duplicate of the arguments.

> `void clone(ConstraintSet set)`

This version clears the `mConstraints` map and re-fills it with the constraints inside the passed-in `ConstraintSet`.

> `void clone(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout)`

This version clears the `mConstraints` map and re-fills it with whatever constraints are necessary to produce a copy of the passed-in `ConstraintLayout`.

> `void clone(Context context, int constraintLayoutId)`

This version uses the passed in `Context` and layout id to inflate a `ConstraintLayout` instance from a layout resource, and then calls `clone(ConstraintLayout)` (the above method).